# QT Relative path issue in ui_ classes

Tags: c++, qt, clang, qmake

I am real beginner in Qt and qmake, and there is a problem with paths of my included headers
I have the following folder structure:

```
projectdir 
└── View 
    ├── Viewer 
    │   └── viewercontainer.h
    ├── mainwindow.h
    └── mainwindow.ui
```

When I promote widget in `mainwindow.ui` (using QtDesigner) I have to specify path to `ViewerContainer` class relative to `projectdir` (like this: `View/Viewer/viewercontainer.h`), although `mainwindow` is in `View/` so logically I should can specify path relative to `View/` directory (like this: Viewer/viewercontainer.h) But it results in errors in `ui_mainwindow.h`, generated by qmake and compiled with clang. Although it does work on another machine that uses MSVC

The question is: can I specify the paths relative to `View/` directory?

One more detail: the .o files in build directory all lie in flat hierarchy without folder structure. Can it be the problem?

Comment: .o files has nothing to do with project folder hierarchy.

Comment: You can specify additional include paths in the .pro file.